# Change file name of toStream() in node.js html-pdf npm module

Tags: html, node.js, pdf, stream, mailgun

I am trying to change the file name of the pdf generated by  the npm module html-pdf.

The issue is I **do not** want to save a copy of the pdf, just stream it to an email service ( mailgun) and then send it off. I have everything working but when I receive the email the file has a default name that I want to change. Does anyone have any experience trying to do this?

Thanks

```
var pdf = require('html-pdf');
var Mailgun = require('mailgun-js');

pdf.create(result).toStream(function(err, stream) {
    var self = this;
    if (err) return console.log(err);

    //set mailgun parameters
     var mail_data = {
        from: 'emailtosendto@email.com',
        to: 'sendingemail@email.com',
        subject: 'subject line',
        html: result,
        attachment: stream
    }
    //send email
    mailgun.messages().send(mail_data, function (err, body) {
        if (err) {
            res.render('error', { error : err});
            console.log("got an error: ", err);
        }
        else {
            console.log(body);
            res.send('ok');
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var pdf = require('html-pdf');
var Mailgun = require('mailgun-js');

pdf.create(result).toBuffer(function(err, buffer) {
    var self = this;
    if (err) return console.log(err);

    var attch = new mailgun.Attachment({data: buffer, filename: 'myattach.pdf'});

    //set mailgun parameters
     var mail_data = {
        from: 'emailtosendto@email.com',
        to: 'sendingemail@email.com',
        subject: 'subject line',
        html: result,
        attachment: attch
    }
    //send email
    mailgun.messages().send(mail_data, function (err, body) {
        if (err) {
            res.render('error', { error : err});
            console.log("got an error: ", err);
        }
        else {
            console.log(body);
            res.send('ok');
        }
    });

});
```

From https://github.com/bojand/mailgun-js#attachments

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I thought this was a html-pdf issue.  I tried this solution and it still seems to not work. The email is sent but there is no attachment now.

Comment: The link I posted mentions that content-type and content-length of the attachment is necessary if the attachment is a Readable, otherwise mailgun ignores the attachment. Since there is no simple way to know the length of a Readable before it is fully consumed, and html-pdf has a toBuffer method, I edited the answer to use a Buffer instead.